# Modifying individual string elements in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int, constants

Good day,
I have an issue with an array, in that I want to change an individual element. I have this:

```
int stats[2] = {0,50};
```

I wish to place this array in a void function and subtract 10 from the second element. Here's what I've tried already:

```
void change(int stats[2]){
stats[1] = atoi(stats[1]) - 10;
```

The error I'm recieving is:

```
Invalid conversion from int to const char*
```

I'm a beginner in C++ so any helpful advice would be immensely appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: `stats` is int type already

Comment: I don't begin to assume you chose the value 50 by accident; it is the asci value of '2'. Is it your intention for `stats[1]` to be `(-8)` when this is finished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `stats[1] = stats[1] - 10`. There are no strings involved in here, so why are you using `atoi`?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the `atoi` function. `stats[1]` is allready an `int`. `atoi` is used to "convert" from the "string" or character representation into the value of the intented `int`. It take a c-string or an null-terminate array of `char`: the `const char *` the compiler have not found. Use simple:

```
stats[1] -=10;
```